# Boss Wants me to Write an Invoice?

Tags: contracts, freelancing, invoices

I've been working at a place for over 6 months now, and my workplace has paid my hours with a government grant. Now they are eligible for up to 12 weeks more funding from another source, but it would require that I write them an invoice, every two weeks.

I told my boss I was unsure because I have been paying into Unemployment insurance, which would be very helpful for me when I have to look for another job.

My boss got back to me a few weeks after this and said if I write the invoice they will continue to give me pay stubs as they always have been and will have the Unemployment insurance and other deductions taken off for me. She also said they will write me a record on employment when they let me go.

However I'm still worried because it is possible that my boss and/or book keeper could get fired. What would happen in that case? Since I'm paying my deductions and still getting pay stubs I would assume I'm still entitled to unemployment insurance and other benefits, but would the fact that I've written them invoices mean I'm a contractor(thus forfeiting those benefits?).

**Location: Ontario, Canada**

Comment: Have you looked at the Ministry of Labour's website, or contacted them asking for clarification on the situation? I don't think you'd be obligated to name names if you contacted them, just say you are confused about the process for this situation and would like clarification.

Comment: I just sent an email, I will let you know what their response is(assuming they respond in time).

Answer (score 9):

If it were me I would suspect that I misunderstood what was being requested.  To clarify I would want to have instructions in writing from the employer on what they expect and what it will mean.

From what you are explaining I think you are right to be concerned.  I would be concerned that my employer was committing fraud and that I was about be become an accidental accomplice.  Though you obviously do not want to accuse them of that outright with no proof, and possibly on the basis of misunderstanding.  Once provided the instructions document, if I am still uncomfortable with it then I would have an attorney read the document and provide further advice.

Should the document satisfy you then I would still retain that document for your records.  If you do get involved in some sort of fraud investigation that document could save you considerable headaches and money.

Comment: Good point @Chad do I really want to risk being involved with fraud, & risk my EI for 12 extra weeks of employment. Not to mention my profession is in high demand right now anyways.

Answer (score 4):

If I was you I'd be asking that question to human resources and not your boss/manager for 2 reasons 1) they know the answer(or at least should) 2) they won't lie or play games.... and if they do lie to you, I'm pretty sure you can get compensation through court.

The whole "boss said" thing doesn't sound right. Do you at least have that in writing somehow in emails etc.? Also I wouldn't be worried about boss or bookkeeper getting fired, I'd be more worried about not getting the unemployment.

Comment: My 'boss' is also human resources, shes not the official boss but basicly runs most of what goes on. The top boss is more of a figure head.

Comment: I mean I don't see what motivation they would have for me to not receive the EI benefits. Though I'm sure the government agency that provided the original grant would frown upon using the grant and then letting the person go right after.

Comment: @PhilipK - It happens pretty regularly in the US...  Government frowning on an action is not the same as having any real consequences for the action.